# Filemaker Pro: How can I limit exported records returned from a layout with a portal?

Tags: filemaker

I'm creating a database for a small magazine in Filemaker Pro 14. Each subscriber can have multiple subscription records, so in the 'Subscriber' layout, I have inserted a portal which shows the list of related subscription records for the subscriber I'm viewing.

When I run a Find operation to view only current subscribers and then export this as a CSV (adding the subscription start and end date as an exported field), I get a list of all current subscribers, but also all the subscription records for each one. I want to limit this so that I only get the current, active subscription record for each subscriber. It looks like this:

> ID, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, begin_issue, end_issue
>   1, John, Doe, 123 Anystreet, Anytown, ST, ZIP, 32.4, 33.3
>   , , , , , , , 33.4, 34.3
>   , , , , , , , 34.4, 35.3

I just want to get:

> ID, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, begin_issue, end_issue
>   1, John, Doe, 123 Anystreet, Anytown, ST, ZIP, 34.4, 35.3

I have created a layout with a portal that includes a filter which only returns the active subscription. However when I export from this layout, I get exactly the same result - it includes all related records.

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to limit this so that I only get the current, active
>   subscription record for each subscriber.

Exports work at the *data* layer, so it doesn't matter what you have on the *layout*. You can have a filtered portal, or no portal at all; still, when you include a related field in the export field order, data from **all** related records will be exported.

To export all (and only) current subscriptions, do your export from the Subscriptions table, after finding only current subscriptions, and include the necessary fields from the Subscribers table.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked. I didn't realize how powerful the export feature of FileMaker was, and was expecting to have to do this all in a query or view (coming from other db software). What I did was exactly what you suggested - export from subscriptions, then I included the fields from the important related tables in the export. FileMaker did all the connecting for me. Excellent!

Answer (score -1):

Simply duplicate this layout, move the fields from the related table directly onto the layout itself, then delete the layout. Only fields from the first related record will be exported. (If you don't get the related record you want, you'll need to adjust the sort order of the relationship you're using).